# Searching a c# List<T> containing inherited class

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

I have created the following code just as a more simplified way to display my problem.

I haven't ran this version through a compiler so it may have typos.

I'm am looking if there is a more condense way (or even a better way) to search a List that contains inherited classes.

```
public class Engine {

  public String FuelType  { get; set; }

}    

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

public class Wheel {

  public String TyreType { get; set; }

}    

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

public abstract class Car {

  public abstract String Model { get; }

}

public class Ford : Car {

  public override String Model {

    get { return "Mustang"; }  // Hardcoded for brevity

  }

  Public Engine Engine { get; set; }

}

public class Porche : Car {

  public override String Model {

    get { return "911"; }  // Hardcoded for brevity

  }

  Public Wheel Wheel { get; set; }

}

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// CarCollection as follows:

// Ford("mustang")   > Engine > FuelType > "Petrol"

// Ford("mustang")   > Engine > FuelType > "Diesel"

// Porche("911")     > Wheel  > TyreType > "Dry"

List<Car> carCollection = GetCarcollection();
```

What I want is a reference to the ' Ford("Mustang") > Engine > FuelType > "Petrol" '. (assume the collection will only contain one)

```
//-- Start --

List<Ford> fordCollection = carCollection.FindAll( cc => cc.Model == "Mustang" )
                                         .Cast<Ford>().ToList();
```

Im not able to access the fuelType in the above so I do it in a seperate statement below.

```
// This 'ford' is the reference I require
Ford ford = fordCollection.Find( fc => fc.Engine.FuelType == "Petrol" );

//-- Finish --
```

Although this works is it possible to combine the two above statement into one.

The Class structure is just a simple example and the design isnt fully relevant to my real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ford = carCollection.FindAll(cc => cc.Make == "Ford")
            .Cast<Ford>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Engine.FuelType == "Petrol");
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't all Cars have Engines?

```
public abstract class Car {

  public abstract String Make { get; }

  public Engine Engine { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `carCollection.OfType<Ford>()`

Perhaps something like this:

```
var ford = (from c in carCollection.OfType<Ford>()
            where c.Model == "Mustang"
            && c.Engine.FuelType == "Petrol"
            select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or

```
var ford = carCollection.OfType<Ford>()
           .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Model == "Mustang" 
                             && c.Engine.FuleType == "Petrol");
```

Comment: This isn't a question about class design as I stated. The classes are purely there as a simple example to ask my question.

Comment: The OfType method should simplify it a bit.

Comment: That probably would work in this example but not in my real code Im actually searching for various Guids the classes and inherited classes contain. Not the class types.

Comment: Does OfType<> use some type of reflection just out of curiosity and doesn't that become quite expensive?

Comment: Sounds like your example doesn't really reflect your problem. Do the different classes have the Guid's you're looking for stored in different ways? Could you define a common interface for them to implement with a method like "ContainsGuid(Guid guidToFind)" ?

Comment: I don't know how OfType is implemented but I expect it's using the as operator rather than reflection.

Comment: Ive altered the example to try and make it clearer. Like I said the class design isn't relevant. Only the search I have created. I'm not trying to change the search as such as it does work. I'm just trying to see if it can be written in a more condensed way.

Comment: Just if anybody is curious if I was searching for the type and not the make the following would work:    Ford ford = fordCollection
                  .OfType<Ford>()
                  .Cast<Ford>().ToList()
                  .Find( fc => fc.Engine.FuelType == "Petrol" );

Comment: The Cast is redundant and, if you use First or FirstOrDefault, so is the ToList.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I assume that this is just a mocked up example and not your real model. As in this case you would probably move engine to the base...So, assuming this is just an example of the issue what you could do is...

```
var fords = carsCollection.OfType<Ford>().ToList();
foreach(var f in fords)
{
  //something with f.Engine
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be pretty, but maybe something like this would work:
`Ford ford = ((List<Ford>)(carCollection.FindAll( cc => cc.Make == "Ford" ))).Find( fc => fc.Engine.FuelType == "Petrol" )`

Comment: I haven't tested but this is more like what I was looking for.